# ssh-keygen - how to set an rsa key with a certain username

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsa, ssh-keys

I just installed ubuntu and would like to set its rsa keys up with bitbucket/github. When I ssh-keygen the keys are generated as they should be

```
ssh-rsa AA...yBEz3pLL georgemauer@ubuntu
```

which is perfectly usable except the username part. In every rsa key I've generated previously, the username section read my email address:

```
ssh-rsa AA...yBEz3pLL gmylastname@gmail.com
```

No, it's not a major impediment but if I don't get this right it will drive me crazy. How, do I generate with rsa keys with an email username of my choice?

Comment: I am wondering how it came that a person with your rep could post such an offtopic here ;)

Comment: @George making coffee is a very common developer activity as well.

Comment: @Eugene true but what stackexchange site do you think is more relevant for this? Serverfault? This is not a common sysadmin activity. Programmers? It's not theoretical, it's a how-do-I question. Superuser? Maybe, but again, this is a common concern for developers and a fairly rare one I would imagine for anyone else.

Comment: @George For me it looks like a superuser.com .

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the `-C` option to provide a new comment with your key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, lowercase `-c` to change a comment

Comment: I needed uppercase C which after inspection realized that this answer uses uppercase `-C`.   I was confused when `ssh-keygen -c "user@host"` didn't work.  I then realized that the answer uses uppercase `-C` which worked when I ran `ssh-keygen -C "user@host"`.

Answer (score 22):

**Explanation:** In general, the last string in your ssh public key would be a single comment which in default configured to your `user@host`. You can override this comment by adding `-C` argument and edit this string.

***For example** In default behaviour, lets say that -  if your linux hostname is `Ubuntu`  and your user name is `john.doe`* while you watch your public key performing `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` you would see something like this:

```
ssh-rsa <someReallyBigToken>== john.doe@ubuntu
```

**Documentation:**

> **ssh-keygen** will by default write keys in an OpenSSH-specific format.
> This format is preferred as it offers better protection for keys at
> rest as well as allowing storage of key
> comments within the private key file itself.  **The key comment may be useful to help identify the key**.  **The comment is initialized to**
> **``user@host'' when the key is created, but**
> **can be changed using the -c option.**

**Solution**: override this comment and use `-C` argument for comment.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C message-in-a-bottle
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

// output:
ssh-rsa <someReallyBigToken>== message-in-a-bottle
```

Answer (score 18):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]
```

I use this command for generating the SSH key for generating GitHub, GitLab, and GCP.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/create-ssh-keys) is the documentation for creating an SSH key with a username.